# .Net Core 3.1, cors policy issue although followed Documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

.Net Core 3.1

I followed a default policy from the official doc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

It is giving me an error from react app. I am not sure what I did wrong here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to place your policy before app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Comment: @alessandro OMG! I love you so much it worked! The reason might be redirection happens before cors has been initialized?

Comment: you can put it in the answer, I will mark you as the answer

Comment: UseStaticFiles middleware is the key, I am sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/13662)

> Unauthenticated preflight requests fail when CORS Middleware comes
> after Authentication Middleware.
>
> This gets ugly here now because we don't also say that Static File
> Middleware has to come after CORS Middleware in scenarios where static
> files require CORS.
>
> We sought to address this in a general way on #10839 because any
> middleware that may use CORS has to come after the CORS Middleware to
> work.
>
> Perhaps, that PR (for the CORS topic) didn't go far enough. I did a
> quick search on the repo, and I don't see a single sample or text
> reference specifically for CORS and Auth Middleware ordering. I can
> open an issue to address it further in the CORS topic, but I'm  for
> a bit if you want me to work it.
>
> For now, I'll ping for engineering. First tho, I'll try to touch this
> up for static files.

As you already know, the order of middleware execution in dotnetcore is important and it seems that the documentation is out of date, so place your policy before app.UseStaticFiles();

All the best